# Foundation not being formatted correctly in React

Tags: reactjs, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to make a simple two-column page using Foundation inside a React JSX file. I have imported the SCSS file and tested some features (i.e. the button, which is stylized correctly), but I can't get the two columns to align side-by-side. Any ideas why these columns are stacking instead of sitting side-by-side?

My index.jsx file

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
require('jquery');

import './styles/app.scss';

// Load foundation
require('style-loader!css-loader!foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css');
$(document).foundation();

class Markdown extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="small-6 columns">6 columns</div>
          <div className="small-6 columns">6 columns</div>
          <button className="success button">Test</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Markdown />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

My app.scss file:

```
@import "base/variables";

//Foundation
@import "base/foundation-settings";
@import "foundation";
@include foundation-everything;
```

My webpack.config.js file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'script-loader!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'script-loader!foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js',
        './app/index.jsx'
    ],
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {

        },
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader", // compiles Sass to CSS
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true,
                    includePaths: [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/foundation-sites/scss'),
                    ]
                }
            }]
        }, {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015']
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

There are no errors in the console, and the Foundation CSS shows up in the DOM.

Comment: Found a fix? How did you solve it?

Comment: I ended up switching to React Flexbox Grid for this project.

Comment: I solved my problem using `require('style-loader!css-loader!foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation-float.min.css');` instead of `require('style-loader!css-loader!foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css');`. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your app.scss file to include foundation-grid like so:

```css
@import "base/variables";

//Foundation
@import "base/foundation-settings";
@import "foundation";
@include foundation-everything;

// Not included in foundation-everything:
@include foundation-grid;
```

From the [Foundation 6 SASS docs](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sass.html):

> Our starter projects include the full list of imports, making it easy
>   to comment out the components you don't need. A full list is also
>   included below.   @import 'foundation';
>
> @include foundation-global-styles;
>
> @include foundation-xy-grid-classes;
>
> //@include foundation-grid;
>
> //@include foundation-flex-grid;
>
> @include foundation-flex-classes;
>
> ...

I was beating my head on the desk for the same reason, with nearly the same setup as you, and happened to stumble upon this minor hint in the tech docs. For whatever reason, "foundation-grid" and "foundation-flex-grid" need to be imported in addition to "foundation-everything" if you want them, as well.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For me, to make foundation working, I have to put this

`componentDidMount() {
    $(document).foundation();
}`

in the root component.

Also, to use jquery, I have to run
`const $ = window.$;`

[set up foundation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMHyD.png)